# Does Tails have a screenshot application?

Tags: tails

Is there an application in Tails where I can take a snapshot of the screen and save it? I have the print screen key on my computer, but am not sure if Tails has an application for it. I will check the applications again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the printscreen key should work.

This can also be invoked through a program called "Screenshot", which provides the same functionality.

This is part of the core Gnome desktop environment which Tails uses.

From the [Gnome user guide](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en):

> 1. Open Screenshot from the Activities overview.
> 2. In the Screenshot window, select whether to grab the whole screen, the current window, or an area of the screen. Set a delay if you need
>      to select a window or otherwise set up your desktop for the
>      screenshot. Then choose any effects you want.
> 3. Click Take Screenshot.
> 4. If you selected Select area to grab, the pointer changes into a crosshair. Click and drag the area you want for the screenshot.
> 5. In the Save Screenshot window, enter a file name and choose a folder, then click Save.
> 6. Alternatively, import the screenshot directly into an image-editing application without saving it first. Click Copy to
>      Clipboard then paste the image in the other application, or drag the
>      screenshot thumbnail to the application.